# "use strict" does not work on ES6 using Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6, use-strict

In `"use strict"` mode, `this` in function should be `[object Window]` rather than the object that calls the function in regular mode. But when I'm trying to proof of concept, it doesn't work, I'm wondering something's wrong with the ES6 extension in Visual Studio Code but I don't know how to figure it out. Can someone help me? :|
Here's the code I used to test `"use strict"`:

```
function name1() {
   document.querySelectorAll("p")[0].innerHTML += this;
}
function name2() {
   "use strict";
   document.querySelectorAll("p")[0].innerHTML += this;
}
document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].addEventListener("click", name1);
document.querySelectorAll("button")[1].addEventListener("click", name2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regard to `this`, strict mode will mean that functions called *without* any calling context - unbound functions not on an object - will receive a `this` of `undefined` instead of the global object.

For example, you'd be able to see the different with the function below:

```
function fn() {
  // use strict here to see the difference
  console.log(this);
}
fn();
```

Strict mode has no effect on the `this` of functions that are called *with* a calling context. Here, both buttons are being called [with a calling context of the button](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events), so the clicked button is the resulting `this` inside the handlers, no matter whether strict mode is used or not.

Nothing to do with VSCode - this is how things'll work anywhere.

```js
function name1() {
   document.querySelectorAll("p")[0].innerHTML += this;
}
function name2() {
   "use strict";
   document.querySelectorAll("p")[0].innerHTML += this;
}
document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].addEventListener("click", name1);
document.querySelectorAll("button")[1].addEventListener("click", name2);
```

```html
<p>p</p>
<button>b1</button>
<button>b2</button>
```

If you want to change the `this` inside a particular click handler, you can

- use an arrow function instead of a `function`
- `.bind` the function, eg `.addEventListener("click", name1.bind(desiredThis));`
- invoke the function inside instead of passing it, eg `.addEventListener("click", () => obj.name1());` will invoke with a `this` of `obj`

Comment: You might mention that you want to override what the click handler sets for `this`, you can use `.bind(someValue)`.